# Bibtex : How to handle 'volume' field with non-numeric information

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am trying to cite a paper whose `volume` contains non-numeric data (see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23902433)).

The bibtex entry that I am trying to use is:

```
@ARTICLE{xu13,
  author = {{Xu}, X. and {Zhang}, Y. and {Williams}, J. and {Antoniou}, E. and {McCombie}, W.~R. and {Wu}, S. and {Zhu}, W. and {Davidson}, N.~O. and {Denoya}, P. and {Li}, E.},
  title = "{Parallel comparison of Illumina RNA-Seq and Affymetrix microarray platforms on transcriptomic profiles generated from 5-aza-deoxy-cytidine treated HT-29 colon cancer cells and simulated datasets}",
  journal = {BMC Bioinformatics},
  keywords = {RNA-Seq microarray comparison},
  year = 2013,
  month = jun,
  volume = 14(Suppl 9), 
  number = S1, 
  pages = {}, 
  doi = {10.1186/1471-2105-14-S9-S1}
}
```

When compiling with bibtex (using TexShop on a Mac), I get the error :

```
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 772 of file references.bib.bib  
:   volume = 14  
:              (Suppl 9), I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry 
(There was 1 error message)
```

QUESTION : How do I handle this supplemental volume information?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just replace `volume = 14(Suppl 9),` with `volume = {14 (Suppl~9)},`. You should probably encase the contents of the `number` field in curly braces as well: `number = {S1},`

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  Perhaps you could make this an answer?

Comment: @Mico Want to get this of the list by either answering or voting to close as off-topic, since this is basically a typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's issue was caused by the equivalent of a typo, *viz.*, missing delimiters around the contents of the `volume` field.